# ASP.NET WebMethod Returns JSON wrapped in quotes

Tags: asp.net, json, asmx

I have an asp.net page with a WebMethod on it to pass JSON back to my javascript.

Bellow is the web method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string getData(Dictionary<string, string> d) {

    string response = "{ \"firstname\": \"John\", \"lastname\": \"Smith\" }";

    return response;

}
```

When this is returned to the client it is formatted as follows:

```
{ \"d\": \"{ \"firstname\": \"John\", \"lastname\": \"Smith\" }\" }
```

The problem is the double quotes wrapping everything under 'd'. Is there something I've missed in the web method or some other means of returning the data without the quotes? I don't really want to be stripping it out on the client everytime. Also I've seen other articles where this doesn't happen.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that you want to return the JSON representation of the object

```
 {
    firstname:"John",
    lastname:"Smith"
 }
```

but your method signature is returning a string.  The ASP.Net framework serialisation **is correctly** serialising the string `response`.  Put another way, if your function was

```
string response = "foo";
return response;
```

You would not be surprised if the output was

```
{"d":{"foo"}}
```

It just happens that `response` has double quotes that need to be escaped.

You obviously just want to get at the object.  You have 2 options: -

1) use `eval` in your javascript to turn the string into an object e.g.

```
function onSuccessCallback(retval) {
     var obj = eval(retval.d);
}`
```

2) or (and this is my prefered solution) have your method return an actual object and let the JSON serialisationof the framework do the heavy lifting for you

```
[WebMethod]
public static object getData(Dictionary<string, string> d) {
    var response = new { firstname = "John", lastname="Smith" };
    return response;
}
```

You will see that this generates the response that you probably originally expected (e.g.
`{"d":{"firstname":"John", "lastname":"Smith"}}`

Comment: PS.  If you want to keep your function returning a string containing the JSON, then I suggest using something like Risk Strahl's ToJson extension function [http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/442969.aspx].  Your method body can then be new {firstname="John"}.ToJson().

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is very interesting. I didn't realise you could create objects that way in c#. However I have already created a framework for building json strings from objects so will have to use the client-side option. I'll look into the server-side option in future projects. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisFewtrell - Thank you so much. I have been returning a STRING for almost 2 years now. This post/answer should be rated much higher

Answer (score 3):

Actually this entire issue exists because you're trying to out-think ASP.Net web services. You need to setup a class for your data to be returned and use that class (or List(of YourClass)) to queue up results and return them.

A great article explaining all this (a very common pitfall) is: http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue with my code. I was trying to return an XmlDocument as JSON to a calling script but returning XmlDocument from the WebService returned an empty set of arrays (as XmlDocument is NOT serializable!).

If i set the ScriptService with the attribute ResponseFormat.JSON then my JSON was double-escaped.

The way to out-fox ASP.NET is to tell ASP.NET that you're returning XML and then it won't double-escape your JSON ;-)

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
    public String MyJSONWebService(String sParam1, String sParam2, String sParam3)
    {
       ... do stuff.....
       XmlDocument oXMLDocument = new XmlDocument();
       oXMLDocument.LoadXml(sXML);
       sJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(oXMLDocument.SelectSingleNode("autnresponse"));
       return sJSON;
    }
```

I know it's a hack but .....