# AJAX - How to retrieve the returned value from my static [webmethod]

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I've got the following PageMethod in my Default.aspx page:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Hello()
{
    return "Hello";
}
```

Here I've got a div text of which I want to set to whatever is returned via AJAX:

```
<div id="ajaxDiv"></div>
```

And below are two ways I invoke AJAX. The first one is the standard AJAX call:

```
 function testAjax()
{
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && status == 200)
        $('#ajaxDiv').text(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", "Default.aspx/Hello", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

And the second one is with the help of JQuery:

```
function testAjaxJQuery()
 {
  $.ajax(
  {
     type: "POST",
     url:"Default.aspx/Hello",
     data: "{}",
     success: function (data)
     {
         $('#ajaxDiv').text(data); 
     }
  }
 )
```

}

I bind a button onclick event to these functions but with both approaches I get the markup of my Default.aspx page, not the word "Hello". What else do I have to do.

Comment: if you add <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="testAjaxJQuery(); return false;"/> does it help? the "return false;" prevents postback.
Also, what happens when you do: $('#ajaxDiv').text('Hello'); Try doing an alert or Console.log on the data returned by ajax (xmlhttp.responseText)

Comment: if I write $('#ajaxDiv').text('Hello'); I get "Hello" in my div. It seems as though xmlhttp.responseText contains all the HTML of the page where my web method resides. It's like AJAX never invokes the method, it rather gets the web page HTML

Comment: And what happens in the JQuery syntax? If you try alert or Console.log in the "success" part of the jQuery call, what is returned? Does that return complete HTML as well?

Comment: check this answer. I think you need to use eval() to unescape the quotes around "Hello". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998455/asp-net-webmethod-returns-json-wrapped-in-quotes

Comment: Yes it' returns HTML in the success part as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use data.d for get response:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "Default.aspx/Hello",
   data: "{}",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {
         $("#ajaxDiv").text(data.d);
   }
});
```

Comment: That way I nothing gets returned. I mean my div text becomes empty

Comment: Thanks mate, that did the job. I got "Hello". :) Of course this was just a test to see if AJAX works.I'll need AJAX for querying a database. What should I do in that case?

Comment: @MikeJM you can generate HTML when into your WebMethode with your Fileds.